# Extra anchors appering in firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser

I'm using FF8 on Linux Mint and I've created a navigation menu using list items. There seems to be extra anchors seems to be appearing at the end of my list items which is causing my css selector ".iconSelect ul li:last-child" to break for some reason!

If I remove the extra anchors via firebug, it works and the styling is applied.

My mark up

```
<div class="iconSelect">
    <ul>
        <li class="abc">
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="./img/user_32x32.png"><a/>
            </div>
            <div class="iconName">tes</div>
        </li>

        <li class="mid">
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="./img/buildings_32x32.png"><a/>
            </div>
            <div class="iconName">Organisationfsdfsd</div>
        </li>

        <li class="xyz">
            <div>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="./img/anchor_32x32.png">
                    <a/>
            </div>
            <div class="iconName">Vessel</div>
        </lI>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Its definitely nothing in the styling or js thats causing this as I've removed them both and the extra anchors still appears.

[image]

Comment: Start reading here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/html

Comment: doh...noob mistake. closing tags problem

Comment: providing some CSS could help a lot

Comment: @Joe I linked the learn HTML form Mozilla above - wouldn't hurt to read through it ... you never know what you might learn !

Comment: @falsarella I mentioned I had removed the CSS and Js.

Comment: @ManseUK What threw me was the fact IE and chrome didnt have that problem. What I learnt from this is to use an automated html validator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your closing anchors are wrong:

```
<a href="#"><img src="./img/buildings_32x32.png"><a/>
                                                  ^^---backwards
```

they should be `</a>`. You've essentially got TWO open tags, and NO closing tags. FF is being polite and auto-closing them for you in the viewer.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `<a/>` instead of `</a>`...

Also in the future you might want to run your HTML trough a HTML validator before posting these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 1):

You close an anchor like this :

```
</a>
```

not

```
<a/>
```

Fix that and your problems will disappear as if by magic. Firefox seems to create the missing elements for you !!